# What is the real every moment exact situation of an a.c source?

Tags: source

in advance of every discussion, i want to say thanks to this great scientific website that i'm recently getting to know it more and more and i'm really happy with.

sometimes i get stuck with really dumb inquiries of my mind! i'm beginner to electronics though. last day, i was reviewing this simple full-wave-bridge-rectifier, almost for the ninth, or the tenth time in my life, and fortunately, i really have no problem with the operation, i understand it all, but...
[image: F-W-B-Rectifier]
but while looking at it, some other question(weird.Q!) sparkled that is this:

when the source is in the positive peak of its signal, and obviously D1 and D2 are forward biased and are conducting, what is the amount of the negative end of the source?!

are the two ends symmetric in their values? e.g. 2V and -2V? so... if yes..., then why we're showing the source voltage in that moment by that positive amount in the figure at all?
or what...?
definitely(or probably...!) it shouldn't have the ground value as well, since the D2 and the D3 are conducting in every half-cycle!
well what is my silly misunderstanding please...!?!?
thank you again ;_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When D2 is conducting, its anode is at GND (0V), and therefore its cathode will be 0.7 V below this, or -0.7 V.

Same situation when D3 conducts -- at that time, the end of the source connected to it is -0.7 V.

When D1 (or D4) is conducting, the end of the source is VOUT + 0.7 V, so the total voltage at the source is VOUT + 2*0.7 V

Comment: thank you very much! but, So... you mean all full wave bridge rectifiers operate only on +,-0.7 volt a.c signals ?

Comment: oops, excuse me, i realized the answer of my own question! 0volts is only a conventional assumption in your answer for the GND! thank's sir!

Comment: *Greater than* 0.7V peak-to-peak, yes. This can be improved to 0.3  using Scottky diodes instead.

Comment: I edited the answer -- VSOURCE is VOUT +2*0.7. So you need VSOURCE greater than 1.4 V peak to get anything out -- that's 2.8 V peak-peak. Schottkys will improve this, so will using MOSFETs as 'ideal' rectifiers

Comment: wow, i got it! you're so helpful, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Not "at the source", but at the transformer coil.  The winding ratio cannot be neglected.

Answer (score 1):

This diagram may better help you to understand how a full-wave bridge rectifier works:

[image]

The + & - signs indicate voltage potential difference (i.e. one end of the wire is greater V than the other end of the wire).  Since AC switches between + & - phases 50 or 60 times per second (depending on your main power source), current flows through a different diode pair with each AC phase transition.

re "...what is the amount of the negative end of the source?!"
For current to flow through a diode, the actual V difference just has to be enough to cause forward biasing to occur (~.7V for silicon diodes).  That means the anode (+) end of the diode must be .7V "more positive" than the cathode (-) side of the diode.  In the USA, during the AC positive (+) phase, the anode will be subjected to a sinusoidal shaped V (which starts at 0V, peaks @ ~170Vac, & then returns back to 0V).  During the AC negative (-) phase, the cathode will be subjected to a sinusoidal shaped V (which starts at 0V, peaks @ ~-170Vac, & then returns back to 0V).
Note: Whenever the anode (+) reaches its forward bias V condition, it will conduct current--even when the anode is 0V & the cathode V is -.7V or less).

Take note of the output from the bridge.  Both arrows indicate the output current is flowing in that direction as positive (+) sinusoidal waves.
Also, if the input is 60 Hz, then the output will be 120 Hz ripple dc.